# $_FILES is empty when drop a file but not with click

Tags: php, jquery, filereader

My JQuery populates $_FILES only when click on input type file but not when drop in a file.

All the examples, tutorials, documentation I have found is about using Ajax or pure JavaScript. None is what I want to do. I have found also plently of plugins, libraries, ... I just want to be able to drop a file.....

The FORM:

```
<form id="item-form" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="image-holder" class="dropBox">
        <img src="" style="width: 100%; padding: 10px;display: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="fileBox">
        <input type="file" name="image_file_input" id="image_file_input" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

The JQUERY:

```
$(".dropBox").on("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    runUpload( e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0] );
});
$(".dropBox").click(function(){
    $("#image_file_input").click();
});
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){
    runUpload( this.files[0] );
});
function runUpload( file ) {
    var reader = new FileReader(), image = new Image();
    reader.readAsDataURL( file );
    reader.onload = function( file ) {
        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
        image_holder.empty();
        $("<img />", {
                        "src": file.target.result,
                        "class": ""
                    }).appendTo(image_holder);
        $("#dropBox").hide();
        $(image_holder).show();
}
```

The PHP:

```
if ( !empty($_FILES) ) {
    echo '---> Files not empty ';
}else{
    echo '---> Files empty ';
}
```

I don't want to use Ajax. I'm only showing the relevant part of the code to concentrate in the issue.

If I click on the dropBox or I drop a file (image) into the dropBox element I can see the image selected in the image_holder div.

When the form is submited if the file is from a click event it works perfectly but when is from a drop event $_FILES is empty.

I'm convinced the problem is what I pass to the runUpload function when dropping. I have tried all sort of things but unable to see what is wrong.

Comment: You only can send a file using a form with enctype. You need to make a object representing a form and append your input file to it.

Comment: The form is  enctype="multipart/form-data". I don't understand your second suggestion. It works when clicking the dropBox object but not when droping a file. Do you know somewhere I can see an example of what you say.

Comment: if you add console.log(file); as the first line in runUpload are you getting the EXACT same thing for click for drop? if not, can you give an example of what shows for each call?

Comment: Click gives:File
​lastModified: 1247549551674
​name: "Chrysanthemum.jpg"
​size: 879394
​type: "image/jpeg"
​webkitRelativePath: ""
​<prototype>: FilePrototype
​​constructor: function ()
​​lastModified: 
​​name: 
​​webkitRelativePath: 
​​<get lastModified()>: function lastModified()
​​<get name()>: function name()
​​<get webkitRelativePath()>: function webkitRelativePath()
​​<prototype>: BlobPrototype { slice: slice(), size: Getter, type: Getter, … }

Comment: Drop gives:File
​lastModified: 1247549551674
​name: "Tulips.jpg"
​size: 620888
​type: "image/jpeg"
​webkitRelativePath: ""
​<prototype>: FilePrototype { name: Getter, lastModified: Getter, webkitRelativePath: Getter, … }

Comment: At a given momento you will need to send the file to write at the server, as javascript is not allowed to write files, so why you don't want to use ajax?

Comment: If I use Ajax on form submit I have to add all form fields to the FormData object, including the file to upload at click and drop events. Why I have to use another way if I have the natural submit. I don't understand why FileReader().readAsDataURL doesn't sends the selected file when is droped (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]) and sends it when clicked ($('input[type=file]').files[0].target.result).

Comment: Yes, I have the turnarround to make all with Ajax but I would like to investigate a litle more about this way. I have made a lot of tests and I think there can be two ways: first is to find out how to add the temporary file to the filesList object of the input or investigate how PHP can read the readAsDataURL info. Any suggestions?.